# Getting extra character after copying the string

Tags: c

I have a written a program in C which is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char text_1[100], text_2[100], text_3[100];
    char *ta, *tb;

    char message[] = "Hello, I am a string; what are you ?";
    printf("Original message: %s\n", message);

    // Copying the message to text_1, the hard way
    int i = 0;
    while (message[i] != '\0' )
    {
        text_1[i] = message[i];
        i++;
    }
    printf("Text_1: %s\n", text_1);
}
```

On executing the above program, I'm getting the following output:

```
Original message: Hello, I am a string; what are you ?
Text_1: Hello, I am a string; what are you ??
```

I'm just confused as to why I'm getting that extra question mark in `Text_1`. I believe `Text_1` should be as exactly similar to `Original message` as per my understanding.

Comment: You didn't copy the terminating NUL character which means `test_1` is not a valid string.

Comment: Either `text_1[i] = 0;` after the loop and before `printf()` or `char text_1[100] = "";` at the beginning (which is only guaranteed for the first copy to `text_1` -- do you understand why?). You can also `do { text_1[i] = message[i]; } while (message[i++]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not null-terminating `Text_1`, so the second `printf()` is going past the last character copied into `Text_1` and is printing random garbage from surrounding memory.

```c
// Copying the message to text_1, the hard way
int i = 0;
while (message[i] != '\0' ) {
    text_1[i] = message[i];
    i++;
}
text_1[i] = '\0'; // <-- ADD THIS!
printf("Text_1: %s\n", text_1);
```

Alternatively, you can pass `i` to `printf()` as the *precision* for `%s`, then you won't need a null terminator, eg:

```c
// Copying the message to text_1, the hard way
int i = 0;
while (message[i] != '\0' ) {
    text_1[i] = message[i];
    i++;
}
printf("Text_1: %.*s\n", i, text_1);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I have it working now. When I'm implementing it as follows: `while ( (text_1[i] = message[i]) != '\0' )  i++;` , I'm getting the right answer although here the logic is the same. Just wondering how is this possible ?

Comment: @AnonSar the logic is NOT the same. The original logic broke the loop **before** copying the null terminator. This new logic breaks the loop **after** copying the null terminator

Comment: Could you please explain how, `printf("Text_1: %.*s\n", i, text_1)` is working. I'm not able to get my head around it., thanks!

Comment: @AnonSar read the documentation for `printf`, it is spelled out in detail

Answer (score 0):

Executed your code  on [Online compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php)

> Output:

```
$gcc -o main *.c
$main
Original message: Hello, I am a string; what are you ?      
Text_1: Hello, I am a string; what are you ?
```

It worked without any abnormal behaviour. However, there is a problem in your code.

```
while (message[i] != '\0' ) { 
  text_1[i] = message[i]; 
  i++; 
}
```

You are copying all character values to `text_1` but forgetting to add `NULL` at the end of `text_1`. As already answered you need to add this

```
text_1[i] = '\0';
```

after your loop.